# How to pass an array to jq to filter results

Tags: arrays, shell, curl, environment-variables, jq

I am fetching list of PR approvals from Github API using `curl` and `jq` to put a label in each PR if conditions are met. I have a few conditions for that namely;

- number of approvals must be at least 2 and
- one of approvers must be in a list that I provide.

In fact, everything is working well but I wanted to beautify my code for example passing the list as an argument rather than having it hardcoded in code. I tried below but it is not working due to:

> jq: error (at :1): Cannot iterate over string ("joedoe,")

```
response=$(curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  --request GET \
  --url https://api.github.com/repos/my-organization/my-repo/pulls/my-pr-number/reviews \
  --header "Authorization: token ***" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json")

requiredViewers=("joedoe", "johnsmith", "johnstiles")

echo $response | jq --arg items $requiredViewers '( map( select( .state=="APPROVED" ) ) | 
                                                    map( { user: .user.login, state: .state, submitted_at: .submitted_at } ) | 
                                                    unique_by( .user ) | 
                                                    sort_by( .submitted_at ) | 
                                                    reverse ) | 
                                                    any( .[].user; . | 
                                                    IN ( $items[] --> this is not working ) ) and 
                                                    length>=2'
```

I had a look at similar posts on SO but couldn't get it to working unfortunately. My question is that how can I pass a list as an argument and make it working as like hardcoding them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve your goal would be to define `requiredViewers` as a JSON array, and to pass it in using `--argjson` instead of `--arg` (assuming your version of jq supports --argjson):

```
requiredViewers='["joedoe", "johnsmith", "johnstiles"]'

echo "$response" |
  jq --argjson items "$requiredViewers" '
    ( map( select( .state=="APPROVED" ) ) 
      | map( { user: .user.login, state, submitted_at } )
      | unique_by( .user ) 
      | sort_by( .submitted_at )
      | reverse )
    | any( .[].user; 
           IN ( $items[] ) ) and length>=2
'
```

#### If your jq does not support `--argjson`

If you cannot upgrade your jq, then one possibility would be to pass the JSON array in as a string using `--arg`, and to use `fromjson` to convert it to a JSON array.

#### Notes

1. The leading '. |' in constructs such as '. | IN(...)' should be omitted.
2. Don't forget to quote your shell variables.
3. The jq expression `{foo: .foo}` can be abbreviated to `{foo}`
4. There are some aspects of your jq program that do not seem to make much sense but in the absence of both explicit requirements and sample JSON, I've focused on the main question.
5. I'd suggest adopting a style that does not require so much right-indentation; the "pipes-on-the-left" style works for me :-)

Comment: Man, you saved my day, I really appreciate it! You don't merely answer the question also suggested great improvements. Sorry I am newbie in `jq` and I'd like to know more about the point 4. How can I simplify this logic? I assume you got my point in this script :)

Comment: Re: (4) -- The calls to `sort_by` and `reverse` don't make sense to me in your program.  If you intended the last filter in your pipeline to be select(any(...) and length>=2), then it would be more efficient to do the sorting after this second selection ....

Comment: I see. Thanks for the heads-up, I will give a try to this!